# Log Structured data to Elastic Search by using NLog 4.5 doesn't provide the ability to query in the fields

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nlog

Using NLog, when I log object/"structured data" to Elastic Search it stored in away that I can not make query on it, Please look to below image:
[image]

```
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
        name="MyElasticTarget"
        uri="url"
        requireAuth="true"
        username="MyUser"
        password="MyPass"
        Index="MyIndex-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
        >
        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" type='JsonLayout' IncludeAllProperties='true'>
          <attribute name='LogMessage' layout='${MySimpleClass:raw=true}' />
        </layout>
      </target>

  </targets>
```

And the code is:

```
  var _simpleObj = new MySimpleClass(5, "my structured Simple obj", "Sometype");
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
            logger.Info("{@MySimpleClass}", _simpleObj );
```

While When I log/store the same Structured data by using SeriLog, I can do query because I have the fields of object out of the message scope and as fields, please look to below image:

[image]

Any Idea how I can log structured data (objects) in be able to query them by use NLog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to enable the **includeAllProperties** property for the [NLog target](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch):

```
<target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" includeAllProperties="true" />
```

You can also add your own custom fields:

```
<target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" includeAllProperties="true">
     <field name="messageTemplate" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
</target>
```

Comment: So it should be in the messageTemplate, this fixed the issue, Thank you @Rolf Kristensen

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **Logstash** filters to decode you json string. I don't know if NLog supports Logstash filters but there are better and more powerful tools that satisfy your need. Log4Net is pretty powerful and widely used library and there is a nice Elasticsearch appneder library for it's **Log4Stash** which supports Logstash filters. It's efficient and easy to use. See link below

http://devthings.com.ua/logging-in-asp-net-web-api-using-log4net-and-elasticsearch/